# How to specify a default argument for a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, default-value, parameter-pack

I have the following method

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices>
void doSomething()
{
    ...
};
```

It seems not possible to supply default values for `Indices`, e.g.

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
void doSomething()
{
    ...
};
```

Compiler complains that

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
                                                                             ^~
error: template parameter pack 'Indices' cannot have a default argument
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
                                    ^~~
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: packs are not allowed to have default arguments.  Generally they way to do this is to make a `template <std::size_t N> void doSomething()` version of `doSomething` and have that call the one with a pack with the desired pack that you want.

Comment: BTW `std::make_index_sequence<N>` is not `std::size_t...`. If legal, you would need something like `std::size_t... Indices = [0, 1, 42]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's already two excellent answers so far (including NathanOliver's comment). I think that having a [couple of overloads that act as wrappers](https://godbolt.org/z/edxe4j7oW) is really the simplest solution here, but just for completeness, let's provide your desired functionality in one function:

Often it's best to take as much of the template logic out of the parameter list as possible (separating inputs from logic):

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Indices>
void doSomething()
{
    using Ints
        = std::conditional_t<
            /* if */ (sizeof...(Indices) > 0),
                std::index_sequence<Indices...>,
            /* else */
                std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

    // ...
};
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ddvobcMcT)

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible. However, you can wrap parameter pack with `index_sequence` and expand them in the function body

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t N, class Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
void doSomething() {
  []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    // expand parameter pack
  }(Indices{});
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hvhKer3ha)